# Using multiple filepond instance in laravel 10 and vue 3 componetns

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, filepond

I have a project in Laravel 10 and Vue 3.
I make use of FilePond to upload profile-image and blog-image in 2 different components.
The problem is when I want to upload a profile image, FilePond uses the blog-image-upload-temparary-file route instead of profile-image-upload-temparary-file route! That's really strange!
In the meanwhile, what I have discovered is. In app.js if I import blogForm component first, then he takes the Profile Image route for both and if I import ProfileForm component first, then he takes the Blog Image route for both.
How can I solve the problem?

```
setOptions({
    server: {
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content
        }, process: {
            url: '/profile/temporary_image_upload',
        }, revert: {
            url: '/profile/temporary_image_delete'
        }
    }
});
```

```
setOptions({
    server: {
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content
        },
        process: {
            url: '/blog/temporary_image_upload',

        },
        revert: {
            url: '/blog/temporary_image_delete'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Filepond has a param where you specify the post route I this it is server option

Comment: I have done that. but it still take the wrong one. If I remove blog component, then he does the right thing

Comment: Show some relevant code